# How do I determine in VBA if a custom spelling dictionary is active?

Tags: vba, spell-checking

How do I determine in VBA if a custom spelling dictionary is active?

I have 4 custom spelling dictionaries Dict1, Dict2, Dict3 and Dict4.

Dict2 and Dict3 have clear tick boxes alongside their entries in the Custom Dictionary dialog box so that they are inactive (File > Options > Proofing > Custom Dictionaries). I am trying to determine in VBA what custom dictionaries are activated.

Method 1 lists all active and inactive custom dictionaries:
Dict1
Dict2
Dict3
Dict4

Method 2. I would expect that the Count property would give 4 which is the total number of dictionaries in the collection, but it actually gives the number of active custom dictionaries which in this example is 2. The result is:
Dict1
Dict2

```
Dim D As Dictionary
Dim k As Long
Dim s As String  

' **** method 1 ****
s = ""
For Each D In Application.CustomDictionaries
   s = s & D.Name & vbCrLf
Next D
MsgBox s

' **** method 2 ****
s = ""
For k = 1 To Application.CustomDictionaries.Count
    s = s & Application.CustomDictionaries(k).Name & vbCrLf
Next k
MsgBox s
```

What I want is a list of only the active dictionaries which in the example should be Dict1 and Dict4. How can I achieve this? Is there an undocumented property that flags a dictionary as being active – as per the tick boxes in the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

As per the API documentation on the Office Dev Center for Microsoft Word VBA, the `Application.CustomDictionaries` property *returns a Dictionaries object that represents the collection of **active** custom dictionaries*

The reference documentation for `Application.CustomDictionaries` on the Office Dev Center can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.customdictionaries).

Hope it helps :-).

Comment: The reference documentation does not explain why the Count property differs from the number of items in the CustomDictionaries collection or how an active custom dictionary can be identified.except to say that active custom dictionaries are marked with a check in the dialog box.